# How to get value in template from model through another one?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models connected by one-to-many relation. How can I get value from one field of one model through another? I need to get value "low" from Image model from the Album model. In my Image model "low" is a path to a low-res copy of image and "path_to_image" is the path to full-size one.

I use Django 2.1, build-in sqlite db.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title

class Image(models.Model):
    path_to_image = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    low = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.path_to_image
```

views.py:

```
def albums(request):
    albums_list = Album.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(albums_list, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    albums = paginator.get_page(page)
    random_idx = random.randint(0, Image.objects.count() - 1)
    image = Image.objects.all()[random_idx]

    context = {
            'albums': albums,
            'image': image,
    }

    return render(request, 'gallery/albums.html', context)
```

albums.html:

```
<div class="item2 my-gallery responsive" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    {% for album in albums %}
       <div class="gallery">
            <a href="/albums/{{ album.id }}">
                <img src="{{album.image_set.model.low}}" width="300" height="225">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">{{album}}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I want to get value from Image model im that `<img>` tag. So, is it possible without refactoring all code entirely? 
(Also, in the views.py I tried to get random image from album to set it as a preview, but it doesn't work too.)

Comment: Can you please clarify. One `Album` contains multiple `Image`s. So in your template, do you want the `low` value for the `image` variable you pass into the template? Or for every image in every album? Or a specific image (for example first) in every album?

Comment: Hi! I want to retrieve Image.low path (to the low-res image) for preview every album. For example I have 4 albums with different images in it and on the albums.html page I want to get one picture from album (it doesn't matter random or first) and set it as a preview for that album. Right now I can only access to the path to full-size image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the `low` value for the first Image in every Album you can do the following:

albums.html:

```
<div class="item2 my-gallery responsive" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    {% for album in albums %}
       <div class="gallery">
            <a href="/albums/{{ album.id }}">
                <img src="{{album.image_set.first.low}}" width="300" height="225">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">{{album}}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The only difference is `{{album.image_set.first.low}}` where we select the first item in the set.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your current view returns a random image, which might not be related to the album at all. I would iterate through the albums and find a random image for each album if this is relevant. Like so:

```
def albums(request):
albums = Album.objects.all()
albums_list = []
for album in albums:
    album_list.append({
        album_images = Image.objects.filter(album=album)
        'id'=album.pk,
        'image_low'= album_images[random.randint(0, album_images.count() - 1)].low
        'title'=album.title
    })
paginator = Paginator(albums_list, 20)
page = request.GET.get('page')
albums = paginator.get_page(page)

context = {
        'albums': albums,
        'image': image,
}

return render(request, 'gallery/albums.html', context)
```

Then you can access the albums in the template like this

```
    <div class="item2 my-gallery responsive" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    {% for album in albums %}
       <div class="gallery">
            <a href="/albums/{{ album.id }}">
                <img src="{{album.image_low}}" width="300" height="225">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">{{album.title}}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```